# Error when using changing mode to csv

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to import data from a csv file. 
According to [this](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv) , I should use `.mode csv` first. But when I enter that command, I get this error:

```
mode should be on of: column html insert line list
```

Why is this so ? 
Google didn't help me much and I'm new to this.

Answer (score 12):

You had probably entered on the SQLite shell using `sqlite`. Try to use `sqlite3` to enter on the shell. There you will have the `.mode csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I entered the shell with sqlite3 and got the same error when I tried to switch modes. I found out the problem was dumber then sqlite vs. sqlite3, I am new to this so newbie error lol

**sqlite> .mode column;        will give the error mentioned ^**

**sqlite> .mode column      without the ; won't**

you can check if the mode actually switched by just running .mode and it will tell you what mode it is on